# Can gnosis safe-core-sdk service function fully offchain with safe-react-gateway-sdk?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, gnosis-chain

The SafeSdk & the gateway API is great, but can it support full offchain signing?

From the doc:

```
User1 signs: safeSdk.signTransaction() is offchain,
User2 signs with: safeSdk.approveTransactionHash()   <-- but this is an onchain call and requires gas.
```

Can `user2~n` just call `safeSdk.signTransaction()` as well and have this recorded on the safe-gateway so that its available in the queue (from getTransactionQueue)??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all the signers can sign a transaction off-chain and send the signature to the Safe Transaction Service, so it appears on the queue in the web UI.

The `@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk` package allows to sign a transaction off-chain like this:

```
...

const safeTxHash = await safeCoreSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction)
const signature = await safeCoreSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash)
```

The `@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client` package allows to send that signature to the Transaction Service:

```
import SafeServiceClient from '@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client'

...

const safeService = new SafeServiceClient({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter })
await safeService.confirmTransaction(safeTxHash, signature.data)
```

You will find a more complete answer following this guide: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md#confirm-transaction